# Parse multiple HTML Tags Bash

Tags: html, bash, awk, sed, grep

How can I parse the following html code?

I have already found out a way to parse "AAA, BBB" 
But its for me impossible to parse "1. CCC" and "DDD"

The output should look like: AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD

```
<td style="background:#edeaea;height:30px;padding-top:10px;" align="center" valign="top">
<a href="design-future">
<img src="../habsr/images2/viels_k/cool.jpg" alt="AAA, BBB" title="cool" style="width:105px;">
1. CCC<br><b><font color="#ff0000">DDD</font></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of `grep` and `sed` can work:

I copy/pasted your text into a file called **blah**.

```
$ grep -o -E "\<[A-Z]{3}\>" blah | xargs | sed 's/ /, /g'

// output
AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD
```

Explanation on the grep:
`-o` captures the *matches* from the grep output (AAA, BBB, etc)
`-E` for the regular expression
`"\<[A-Z]{3}\>"` 3-letter A-Z matches on a word boundary
The pipe to `xargs` gets a single line from the grep output (separated by spaces)

The last pipe to `sed` simply converts the spaces to comma-space to achieve your desired output.